# KeycloakSecurityContext is returning null in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am creating an SPA with Keycloak 5, Spring Boot 2 and Angular 7.

Everything was fine, even keycloack configuration in `application.properties` and roles securing. But when I tried to create a Bean to get the User Token Data, I am receiving a null bean of it. Can't understand why, it is just like the code in Keycloak documentation...

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    /**
     * Retorna o contexto de seguranÃ§a do Keycloak.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public KeycloakSecurityContext accessToken() {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        return (KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Boot Config:

```
    keycloak.enabled                    = true
    keycloak.auth-server-url            = http://acesso.tre-pa.jus.br/auth
    keycloak.realm                      = TRE-PA
    keycloak.resource                   = acesso-sistemas-service
    keycloak.credentials.secret         = ca70294a-af51-4abb-81f9-234566de2c7c
    keycloak.ssl-required               = external
    keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = false
    keycloak.bearer-only                = true
    keycloak.autodetect-bearer-only     = true
    keycloak.principal-attribute        = preferred_username
    logging.level.org.keycloak          = DEBUG 

    spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true

    # spring.autoconfigure.exclude        = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfiguration

    keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name        = secured-area
    keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /secured/*
    keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[1] = /admin/*

    keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0]                       = DEVELOPER
    keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name        = service-area
    keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /service/*
```

Comment: Can you link to the keycloak docs part which explains to do it this way? You're basically telling you want an attribute in the current HTTP request called `org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext`, which I don't think it exists.. You should be retrieving this from session IMO..

Comment: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-October/011948.html

Comment: Maybe that way is not valid anymore since it's a different version.

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords I am running into same problem. If you have found any solution please tell me. Also can you tell me where you found the documentation of keycloak-spring-boot-starter?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in my application using Keycloak `4.8.1.Final` where I could access the `AccessToken` and expose it as a bean for injection into other classes:

```
 @Bean
 @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 public AccessToken getAccessToken() {

     HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
     KeycloakPrincipal<RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext> keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();

     if (keycloakPrincipal == null) {
         throw new NotAuthenticatedException("KeycloakPrincipal not set");
     }

     KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();

     return keycloakSecurityContext.getToken();

 }
```

After upgrading Keycloak to 5 (and above all the way to 15.0.1) the code above no longer works. The only way I managed to get a reference to the AccessToken was by using Spring Security as described (mostly) [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#spring-security-configuration)

Basically adding spring security deps to gradle

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
```

Adding this config class...

```
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy
import javax.inject.Inject

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
class KeycloakConfig : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

     override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
        http.csrf().disable()
    }

    @Inject
    fun configureGlobal(authManager: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val authProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider()
        authProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(SimpleAuthorityMapper())
        authManager.authenticationProvider(authProvider)
    }

    @Bean
    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
        return RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())
    }

}
```

And then updating my method in my other config class:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes
import org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal
import org.keycloak.adapters.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext

    @Configuration
    class ApplicationConfig {

    //needed for keycloak adaptor 7.0.1+
    // added in this here rather than in KeycloakConfig above due to issue here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957006/unable-to-build-spring-based-project-for-authentication-using-keycloak
    @Bean
    fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
        return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun accessToken(): AccessToken {

        val request = (RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes).request

        val token = request.userPrincipal as KeycloakAuthenticationToken? ?: throw NotAuthorizedException("KeycloakPrincipal not set")
        val principal = token.principal as KeycloakPrincipal<*>
        val keycloakSecurityContext = principal.keycloakSecurityContext

        return keycloakSecurityContext.token
    }
}
```

The above codes works for me with Springboot versions `2.1.2.RELEASE` and `2.5.3`